# Javascript-oriented Firebug plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firebug

Does anyone know of a browser plugin (Ch or FF) or perhaps a Firebug plugin, which would show me all attached event javascript handlers to currently selected DOM element? I have to debug one site that I received to take care of, with lots of spaghetti-style javascript.

Comment: Were they added by jQuery / any other framework, or are they simple DOM addEventListeners?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find event listeners on a DOM node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chrome, I guess the normal dev tool would do: http://screencast.com/t/KHKeMIj6BiDk (this is a Safari actually, but this should come with other webkit desktop browers as well)

In the meanwhile, read this stackoverflow question: [How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

Comment: Visual Event is awesome! Thanks.